# Header and footer is not loading for inner cms pages in magento 2

Tags: magento2

After indexing the cms block and flush the cache, Header and footer is not loading for inner CMS pages in **Magento 2**.

Comment: Header footer not loading for cms pages only or on entire site ? Catalog, cart, cms etc

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 2):

Check cms page **Design** tab and set **layout** as per your requirement.

and check.

[image]

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: when i click over the product category in the menu the product page is look like that in which there is no header footer

Comment: no homepage is showing good but when i click on any product category the product listing page is looking clutter and the css are not loading in header and footer